# share dynamic text content on whatsapp with format?

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I have used this code to share the dynamic text of my web page on whatsapp, the drawback is that it takes the plain text.

**Would there be an option to add so that it reads the text with  format**

```html
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class='divblock'>
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
</div>
    <button id='button'> WHATSAPP </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function clickMe() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  var divblock = $('.divblock').text();
  button.addEventListener("click", event => {
    // Whatsapp Message on Button Click
    window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Show div text: " + divblock)
  });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share html content through whatsapp api. Whatsapp supports basic formatting - Bold, Italic, Strikethrough and Monospace.
You can use regex to find the above html tags and replace it with Whatsapp formatting syntax as mentioned in https://faq.whatsapp.com/556797335179788

Comment: Understood, do you have any idea how to make it show the spaces the text copies it to me in a row